# Magento 1.9: export a list of orders with specific data

Tags: magento-1.9, reports

I need to create report or export orders list as csv file, on a specified date range, where each of them have these data:

- order id
- date
- import
- products quantity
- payment method

I am tried to `Reports>Sales` section in the backoffice but I never can get **all** the above dates.

I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.3.3

Answer (score 3):

I have create order export script. please review it.

Note -> please update app/Mage.php path as your requirement

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
ini_set('max_execution_time','1800000000');

define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once  (MAGENTO_ROOT . '../../app/Mage.php');

Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::init();

$fromDate = '2016-12-01 00:00:00';
$toDate = '2017-04-01 00:00:00';//$toDate = '2017-05-31 23:59:59';

$order = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection');
$order->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate,'to'=>$toDate));
$order->setOrder('increment_id', 'DESC');

$fp = fopen('sales-order-export.csv', 'w');
$field = array('OrderNumber','Date','products quantity','payment method');
fputcsv($fp, $field);
echo "<pre>";
foreach($order as $orders)
{
    $countTotalQty = 0; 
    foreach ($orders->getAllItems() as $item)
    {
        $countTotalQty = $countTotalQty + $item->getQtyOrdered();
    }
    $payment = $orders->getPayment();
    $fields = array($orders->getIncrementId(),$orders->getCreatedAt(),$countTotalQty,$payment->getMethod());
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);


}
```

I hope it will help you